# Why my final image turned into red after putpixel?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am gonna eliminate the ‘noise’ of the images, mainly is salt-n-pepper noise by using sorting and then assigns the mean value to the coordinate. The result should be based on the previous color, but what I got turned into RED..

Is there any parameter wrong with this? Big thanks!

```
from PIL import Image

path='MonaLisa.png'
img=Image.open(path)
members=[(0,0)]*9 
size=width,height=img.size;
newimg=Image.new("RGB",(width,height),"white")


for i in range(1,width-1):
    for j in range(1,height-1):
        members[0] = img.getpixel((i-1,j-1))
        members[1] = img.getpixel((i-1,j))
        members[2] = img.getpixel((i-1,j+1))
        members[3] = img.getpixel((i,j-1))
        members[4] = img.getpixel((i,j))
        members[5] = img.getpixel((i,j+1))
        members[6] = img.getpixel((i+1,j-1))
        members[7] = img.getpixel((i+enter image description here1,j))
        members[8] = img.getpixel((i+1,j+1))
        members.sort()
        newimg.putpixel((i,j),(members[4]))
newimg.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is not a `mean` filter (where each pixel is replaced by the average of its neighbours), but a `median` filter (where the neighbours of each pixel are sorted and the central or median value is used as the new pixel).

Firstly, it is much more easily done using PIL/Pillow's built-in  [PIL.ImageFilter.MedianFilter](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/ImageFilter.html?highlight=median). I guess you are writing it from scratch to learn some image processing. So let's assume that.

As you haven't provided a sample image, it is difficult to say for sure what is wrong. However, I would guess that the problem is either:

- `MonaLisa.png` is a colour image and you are only processing one channel of greyscale values because you only loop over image height and width, but not over 3 RGB channels, or
- `MonaLisa.png` is a greyscale image but it is palettised and the numbers you are looking at are indices into a colour palette rather than actual RGB values.

So, let's assume you intend to process in greyscale, you need to ensure that your input image is greyscale (rather than colour) and greyscale values (rather than palette indices), so you need to use:

```
# Open image as greyscale, not palettised, not colour
img=Image.open(path).convert('L')
```

Secondly, your output image should also be greyscale, so:

```
newimg=Image.new("L",(width,height),"white")
```

The reason your image became red was because you only write one byte for each pixel rather than the 3 bytes of RGB you need, and so only the first channel (Red) gets written.